# Как изменить цвет выводимого в консоль текста?

Tags: java, io

Мне нужно написать консольное приложение, в котором через `System.out.println("Какой-то текст");` выводится текст.

Возможно ли как-то в коде задать цвет текста ?

Comment: [Урок о том как выводить цветные символы на консоль.](https://youtu.be/UwBdtgBNZfw)

Answer (score 12):

Да, это [возможно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762502/7129209) (но работать будет не везде):

```
public class Main {
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
    public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
    public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "This text is red!" + ANSI_RESET);
    }
}
```